# Flutter how to make table like UI

Tags: flutter, user-interface, flutter-layout

I am new in flutter just want to know using which widget I can create UI like given in below image. I tried a `Table` but then my `Textfield`s are so much oversized and not in a line with the text. Any Help? Thx!

```
 return Container(

      padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),

      child: Table(
       // border: TableBorder.all(color: non),
        children: [
          TableRow(

              children: [
            Text('Bizeps(l)'),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 20.0,

                  child: const Card(child: TextField()),
                ),

            Text('cm'),
            IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.add_circle_outline)),
            IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.remove_circle_outline)),

          ]),
          TableRow(children: [
            Text('Bizeps(l)'),
            SizedBox(
              width: 30.0,
              child: const Card(child: TextField()),
            ),

            Text('cm'),
            IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.add_circle_outline)),
            IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.remove_circle_outline)),
          ])
        ],
      ),);
    
  }
```

My Result:

[image: img1]

Goal:

[image: img2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set `defaultVerticalAlignment: TableCellVerticalAlignment.middle` for the table to align the text in line with the buttons. To reduce the `TextField` size you can set its height as well as its width. Keep in mind that in the *Goal* picture there is no `Card` wrapping the `TextField`s.

```
Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        child: Table(
          defaultVerticalAlignment: TableCellVerticalAlignment.middle, // this is new
          children: [
            TableRow(children: [
              Text(
                'Bizeps(l)',
              ),
              SizedBox(
                width: 20.0,
                height: 50.0, // this is new
                child: const Card(child: TextField()),
              ),
              Text('cm'),
              IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.add_circle_outline)),
              IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.remove_circle_outline)),
            ]),
            TableRow(children: [
              Text('Bizeps(l)'),
              SizedBox(
                width: 20.0,
                height: 50.0, // this is new
                child: const Card(child: TextField()),
              ),
              Text('cm'),
              IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.add_circle_outline)),
              IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.remove_circle_outline)),
            ])
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: Thx that helped me a lot! And great hint with the card :)

Answer (score 0):

Combine `Column` with `Rows` to take your result.

```dart
 Widget rowWidget() {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: [
        Text('Bizeps(l)'),
        TextField(),
        Text('cm'),
        IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.add_circle_outline),
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
        IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.remove_circle_outline),
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget columnWidget() {
    return Column(
      children: [
        rowWidget(),
        rowWidget(),
        rowWidget(),
      ],
    );
  }
```